# How do I calculate proficiency advancement for multiclass characters?

Tags: multi-classing, adnd-2e, character-advancement

My question is about my multiclass character, a cleric/thief.

I read that the cleric class gains 1/4 weapon and 1/3 nonweapon proficiencies, while the thief class gains 1/4 for both kinds of proficiency.

I now hit level 8 for the cleric and 9 for the thief.
Does this mean I get, taking nonweapon proficiency as an example, 1/3 × 7 for the priest **and** 1/4 × 8 for the thief level-ups, or does it calculate only for the class to reach a level first, meaning i get only one of those class points or only the half of the sum for both classes? What about for weapon proficiencies?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for your inquiry; in particular its narrow scope and application to a specific, solvable problem make this a good question.  Please [visit our help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) when you have time, and we hope to see you around the next time you have a question :)

Comment: Also, since you now have enough rep, you can ask more open ended discussion type questions in chat if you need to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the best progression from your two classes. *Player's Handbook*, "Multi-CLass Benefits and Restrictions", page 44, last paragraph before the multi-classing example:

> If the optional proficiency system is used, the character […] gains new proficiency slots at the fastest of the given rates.

which is reiterated on page 52, end of the first full paragraph:

> Multi-class characters can use the most beneficial line on Table 34 to determine their initial proficiencies and when they gain new proficiencies.

You apply this progression as you gain levels, which ends up meaning that it applies to both classes separately. Your Cleric 8 / Thief 9 should have gained 1/4 × 8 = 2 weapon proficiencies† and 1/3 × 8 = 2 NWPs (rounded down) from cleric advancement since 1st level; plus 1/4 × 9 = 2 weapon proficiencies (rounded down) and 1/3 × 9 = 3 NWPs from thief advancement since 1st level; for a total of 4 WPs and 5 NWPs gained since 1st level.

A common interpretation of the multi-classing rules is that you must fill each weapon and non-weapon proficiency slot according to the restrictions of the class level that earned it; consult with your DM to see how they handle this. Regardless of that, see the notes on multi-class priest weapon usage restrictions on page 45 of the *Player's Handbook* before you choose any thief weapon proficiencies that you might not be able to use.

---

† Though one might expect this should be multiplied by level − 1 (not the full number of levels) since you already get stuff at 1st level, the rules are more generous and grant new proficiencies at each level divisible by the rate. See PHB p. 50, "# Levels" (centre column, 3rd paragraph).

Comment: Well written with example math, and a cautionary reference to boot. Nicely done!

Comment: Thanks for the very fine example. I only got one questions. In both cases, you multiplied the improvement per level by the level, not by level-1. Shouldn't it be -1 cause you already start with level 1? Or is it possible to start without a level? I expected to get (by the method you suggested) 2 WP (thief) plus 1.75 WP(cleric) and 2.33 NWP (thief) plus 2 NWP (cleric), which would be 3.75 WP plus 4.33 NWP overall.

Comment: That would be a reasonable way to write the rules, but they didn't go with level-1. Instead they went with levels divisible by the rate; so a Fighter gets new WP at 1/3, getting a new one at 3rd level. See PHB p. 50, "# Levels" (centre column).

Comment: (I've added that to the answer now.)

Comment: Thanks. Thinking of it as every 3rd or 4th level makes sense and the best explanation. I marked it as solution now.