# Literacy and Dual Classing AD&D Proficiencies?

Tags: adnd-2e, proficiency, multi-classing

I've got a bunch of players about to dual class and they aren't supposed to use their old class abilities, but some basic things bother me:

- Reading/Writing
- Their Native Language
- Foreign languages like Elven or Dwarven
- Riding Horses/Landbased
- Steering Dogsleds/Animal Handling

And proficiencies with weapons they already will use anyway, I find it concerning that the Rules as Written seem positively unplayable and ridiculous if taken to the extreme.

Do they become illiterate mutes unable to ride horses lest they gain 0 XP?

Do they dump all their new proficiencies into buying literacy and so on all over again?

My main concern is with "General" proficiencies available to all classes, "Literacy/Language" proficiencies, and weapons which the new class already permits, like staff or dagger.

Not using a dagger when the new class permits it because you don't want to pay for it twice is somewhat bad, but not being able to speak or read the signs on the Inn's "jobs posted" board seems an excessive abuse of rules lawyering.

Comment: one idea that popped into my head is letting the player's intelligence based languages/bonus weapons/bonus languages be a guide for how many proficiencies were NOT class based and operate independently. Typically 2-7. This keeps wizards literate and fighters proficient in daggers.

Comment: Related: [How do dual-class humans gain proficiencies beyond their first class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106969/how-do-dual-class-humans-gain-proficiencies-beyond-their-first-class)

Comment: Ive just suggested [tag:dual-classing] as a syonym of [tag:multi-classing]. No reason to have both, the multiclassing tag is generic.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov With only two questions tagged dual-classing,  both specific to 2e, and no usage guidance on the tag itself, I think that's fair.  Until it is accepted as a synonym, though, dual-classing is the better tag for this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This is not nearly as bad as you think it is

**Dual-class Benefits and Restrictions:**

> Instead, he starts over in a new class, at 1st level with 0 experience points, but he does retain his previous Hit Dice and hit points. He gains the abilities, and must abide by all of the restrictions, of the new class.

"[G]ains the abilities" of the new class means that you get a whole suite of new proficiency slots.  As Table 34 shows, depending on what your new class is, you gain 1-4 new weapon proficiency slots and 3-4 nonweapon proficiency slots.  I don't think you would get more bonus slots for Intelligence, since that is a function of your ability score and not your class, strictly speaking.  So you have a net gain of between 4 and 8 slots to spend on new things if you wish.

**Dual-class Benefits and Restrictions:**

> This is not to imply that a dual-class human forgets everything he knew before; he still has, at his fingertips, all the knowledge, abilities, and proficiencies of his old class. But if he uses any of his previous class's abilities during an encounter, he earns no experience for that encounter and only half experience for the adventure.

As Ben Barden [points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205621/literacy-and-dual-classing-add-proficiencies/205623#comment563537_205623), you lose xp if you use the abilities from the previous class *during an encounter*.  If you are at the tavern between adventures, conversing casually with a dwarf in Dwarven, or reading the notice board, you are probably not in an encounter.  You can use Dwarven or Reading proficiencies with no xp penalty.  Now if the dwarf suddenly draws his blade and shouts something to the other dwarves in the room, and the DM tells you to roll Initiative...Then you would need to decide to use your old Dwarven language NWP to know what he said (at the cost of experience in the encounter), or to simply forge ahead not knowing what was said.

**Dual-class Benefits and Restrictions:**

> The only values that can be carried over from the previous class without restriction are the character's Hit Dice and hit points. The character is penalized for using his old attack or saving throw numbers, weapons or armor that are now prohibited, and any special abilities of the old class that are not also abilities of the new class. (The character is trying to learn new ways to do things; by slipping back to his old methods, he has set back his learning in his new character class.)

Now, as you say, you might want access to 'old' proficiencies, and it may be irksome to 'pay for things you already know' just so you can use them without having to lose xp.  But even if you do that for a few key proficiencies, you are still gaining a bunch more.  However, I think you are overestimating what exactly you have to pay to retain what you already know.  For one thing, you should never have spent a proficiency on *speaking* your **native language** to begin with, and you certainly don't have to re-pay for that now:

**Table 4 (Intelligence):**

> The character never needs to spend any proficiency slots to speak his native language.

**Table 8 (Racial Ability Adjustments):**

> Racial languages for demi-humans can be handled in either of two ways, depending on whether or not your DM uses the optional proficiency system.  Either way, your character automatically knows his native language.

So no, your new dual-class character is not mute (or, perhaps an aglot?).

**Reading / Writing**.  You will have to pay for that again in order to be able to access it *during an encounter.*  Will it be essential for you to be able to read when the arrows are flying?  Perhaps if your new class is Priest or Wizard and you are reading a Protection scroll, but at least that is only one slot - you can likely afford that from your 3-4 NWP gain.  If your new class is Rogue or Warrior, then it is probably not worth the two slots.  Is that crippling?  I don't think so, if you remember that this applies only during encounters.

**Foreign Languages** depend on how you got them.  If you are a demi-human, maybe you picked them up as a racial bonus.  If you did spend a proficiency slot on them, then yes, you would need to 'waste' a slot to keep access *during encounters*.  It seems like you could usually wait until outside of combat to use these proficiencies, though.

**Riding Horses/Land-based Steering Dogsleds/Animal Handling**.  Here it is essential to understand that you don't *need* a proficiency in riding in order to ride a horse, even in an encounter - it is just that having the proficiency makes you a *better* rider, able to do tricks, stay in the saddle under difficult conditions, and so forth.  Make sure you read the descriptions of the proficiencies carefully.  Animal handling, for example, "enables a character to exercise a greater-than-normal degree of control over pack animals and beasts of burden".  If it is sufficient to have just a *normal* degree of control over your beasts of burden, then simply accept the decreased performance during encounters.  If it is essential to your character to be an expert rider even in encounters, than yes, you will have to pay for that.

**Proficiencies with weapons they already will use anyway**.  Here again, note carefully what the rules actually say: "The character is penalized for...weapons or armor that are now prohibited...".  The only weapons and armor that you are not permitted to use at all are the ones not permitted to your new class, which makes sense.  If you dual-class Warrior to Wizard, you *shouldn't* be swinging a sword until your Wizard prowess is better than your old warrior level, and if you do, if you fall back on your Warrior knowledge and use a weapon barred to Wizards, then you lose any experience you might have gained as a Wizard for that encounter.  But if you are going from Wizard to Warrior, does that mean you *can't* use a dagger without paying for the proficiency as a Warrior when you already had the proficiency as a Wizard?  **No**.  It just means you can't use your *proficiency* in dagger without paying for it - that is, you would need to use the dagger as a non-proficient weapon, with the non-proficiency penalty - which as a Warrior, is only -2.  You can use the *dagger* without losing xp (because the dagger is permitted to your current class), just not the dagger *proficiency* (because you haven't 'bought' that for your current class).

In conclusion, you will retain full function in some abilities without having to pay for them at all (like your native language).  For other abilities you will have to accept a decrease in performance, but you will not fully lose use of them (like riding or some weapons).  Still others you will either have to give up entirely, though only during encounters, or actually 'waste' slots paying for them again (like reading and foreign languages).  Even if you pick out a few proficiencies you can't live without during encounters, I bet you will still find that dual-classing results in a net gain of proficiencies.

Finally, remember that if you spend multiple slots on the same weapon proficiency you can gain specialization, and if you do so on the same NWP you gain a bonus to your checks.  If there is some skill you really can't afford to lose during combat and you end up paying for it twice, then once you regain access to your old class abilities I would certainly remind the DM that you have spent *two* slots on that proficiency and ask them for specialization.

Comment: Further worth noting that you are only penalized for using your previous class abilities *during an encounter*.  Doing things like reading a book or riding your horse outside of an encounter allows you to use your initial abilities without additional penalty.

Comment: @BenBarden Excellent point - since you are trying to use the new abilities rather than fall back on your old ones in stressful situations.  So unless a bar fight breaks out while you are trying to read the notice board, you are good to read it.  Will amend.

Comment: Class abilities are the the things that are *described in that class*. Like detect evil by paladins, shape change by druids, tracking by rangers, climb walls by thieves. If a thief picked up the tracking NWP before dual classing to mage .. that mage can use the tracking NWP with no penalty because it's not a class ability. If that mage used climb walls then the penalty applies.

Comment: @Erics Most of the uses of "class abilities" in the PHB refer to ability scores.  There is, AFAICT, no explicit definition of what a class ability is, and the only one identified as such is the paladin's detect evil.  So it may be that you are right that class ability in the strict sense are the things like you mention.   However, the quote in the rules about what is prohibited makes it clear that class abilities there is being used in the broad sense to mean everything except hp and HD: "This is not to imply that a dual-class human forgets **everything** he knew before;...

Comment: he still has, at his fingertips, **all the knowledge, abilities, and proficiencies** of his old class. But if he uses any of his previous class's abilities during an encounter, he earns no experience for that encounter and only half experience for the adventure. The only values that can be carried over from the previous class without restriction are the character's Hit Dice and hit points. The character is penalized for using his old attack or saving throw numbers, weapons or armor that are now prohibited, and any special abilities of the old class that are not also abilities of the new class.